# How to fix ADSync exception error when starting Delta sync with powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

When I try to kick off a Delta Sync through a pssession a error is thrown. If I run the commands one line at a time it runs perfectly fine.

```
Enter-PSSession server_name
Get-Module ADSync | Import-Module
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta 
Exit-PSSession
```

I expect it to start the Sync but just get the error:

> 'Microsoft.DirectoryServices.MetadirectoryServices.UI.PropertySheetBase.UIUtils'
>   threw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that ended up working out for me was to invoke the command rather then enter a pssession. I am not sure why this works, but it does.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server_name -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock{
    Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin\ADSync"
    Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually perform a `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle` through a helper function that detects if the ADSyncScheduler is suspended and also detects if there maybe already a sync cycle in progress. Without watching for these things you may receive errors.

```
function Start-SyncCycle {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateSet('Delta','Initial')]
        [string]$PolicyType = 'Delta'
    )
    # test if the ADSyncScheduler is not suspended
    $scheduler = Get-ADSyncScheduler
    if ($scheduler.SchedulerSuspended) {
        # SchedulerSuspended is set during an upgrade to temporarily block the scheduler from running. 
        # When this property is $true, running Start-ADSyncSyncCycle wil result in error:
        # System.InvalidOperationException: Scheduler is already suspended via global parameters.

        Set-ADSyncScheduler -SchedulerSuspended $false
    }
    # test if a scheduled synchronization is already running
    if ($scheduler.SyncCycleInProgress) {  # or use: if (Get-ADSyncConnectorRunStatus) { ... }
        Write-Warning "A sync is already in progress. Please try again later."
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Initializing Azure AD $PolicyType Sync..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        try {
            Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType $PolicyType -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null

            Write-Host "Waiting for Sync to start.."
            # give the Sync Connector some time to start up (10 seconds should be enough)
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

            Write-Host "Waiting for Sync to finish.."
            While(Get-ADSyncConnectorRunStatus) {
                Write-Host "." -NoNewline
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            }
            Write-Host
            Write-Host "Azure AD $PolicyType Sync has finished." -ForegroundColor Green

        }
        catch {
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}
```

You use the function like this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName "your.username@yourdomain.com" -Message "Please enter credentials for yourdomain.com"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $AzureConnectServer -ScriptBlock ${function:Start-SyncCycle} -Credential $cred
```

Hope that helps